# Install Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection, ipv4

I can not explain what has happened, just suddenly I lost my internet connection. On local area connection properties IPv4 is not installed, my ISP says that they only support IPv4. Then I must had it because I had connection before. 
What could happen to lose IPv4? And how to install it back?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the network connection?

Comment: @Ramhound Local area connection has disabled delete option in context menu. Do you mean that? I did create another wireless connection via wireless usb adapter, and it also is missing IPv4. Thanks.

Comment: Well its not possible to disable the IPV4 Adapter.  Specific information about the hardware in question would be helpful.  Have you tried a non-wireless connection?

Comment: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller is network card.

Comment: Have you tried a System Restore back to before it broke?

Comment: No I did not. I know only that system was not rebooted for long time, then after one reboot it went down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

way 1:

Run `cmd` as Administrator. Run command:

```
netsh interface IPV4 uninstall
```

Wait 2-3 minutes, run:

```
netsh interface IPV4 install
```

way 2:

Run `cmd` as Administrator. Run command:

resets WINSOCK entries to installation defaults

```
netsh winsock reset catalog
```

resets IPv4 TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

```
netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log
```

or

```
netsh int ip reset reset.log
```

need reboot

way 3:

Run `ncpa.cpl` as Administrator.

Right-click the network connection which you are using, and then click Properties.

Click on Internet Protocol TCP/IPv4.

Click Install then.

Click Protocol, and then click Add.

Click Have Disk.

Type the location as `%windir\inf%`, example: C:\windows\inf and then click OK.

On the list of available protocols, click Internet Protocol (TCP/IPv4), and then click OK.

way 4:

```
wmic nicconfig get MACAddress, IPAddress, ServiceName, Caption, IPEnabled, SettingID | find /I "Realtek"
```

Get NIC GUID and del `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet00x\Services\{GUID}` in registry.

```
wmic nic get Caption, PNPDeviceID, ServiceName, NetConnectionStatus | find /I "Realtek"
```

Get NIC PCI ID: PCI\VEN_XXXX&DEV_YYYY&SUBSYS_ZZZZZZZ&REV_TT and del `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet00x\Enum\PCI\VEN_{PCI_ID}` in registry.

If it is difficult steps to improve law, registry entries, and then override the owner can use the Windows Driver Kit (WDK) 7.1.0.

Run `regedit` with SYSTEM rights.Need [Windows Driver Kit (WDK) 7.1.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11800):

```
ntsd -c qd regedit
```

Scott Chamberlain (c), good comment!:

You can run regedit with SYSTEM rights by using [PSExec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) too, much smaller download. One of the examples they post is running regedit as SYSTEM.

```
psexec -i -d -s c:\windows\regedit.exe
```

Reboot!

way 5 (apply if in a pinch, if the previous methods did not help):

/1. Back up Registry
/2. Edit file %windir%\inf\Nettcpip.inf in `[MS_TCPIP.PrimaryInstall]`

comment string `;`:

```
;    Characteristics = 0xA0 ; NCF_HAS_UI | NCF_NOT_USER_REMOVABLE
```

and add

```
Characteristics = 0x80
```

[image: Nettcpip.inf ipv4 enable Uninstall]

/3. Control Panel->Network Connections->Local Area Connection->Properties

[image]

Install protocol. Press Install button, select protocol, type `Windows` `Inf` path.

[image]

Select IPv4 protocol. (Unblock IPv4 `uninstall` button.)

[image]

Uninstall IPv4.

[image]

/4. delete registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Winsock
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Winsock2
```

if need, delete registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\tcpip
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\dhcp
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\dnscache
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\ipsec
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\policyagent
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\atmarpc
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\nla
```

[image]

## /5.Reboot

[image]

/6. Install IPv4

[image]

## /7. Reboot!

[image]

## /8. Restore %windir%\inf\Nettcpip.inf

/*. See too [Re-installing WAN miniport devices](https://web.archive.org/web/20200807172058/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/BrentCaskey/archive/2011/06/09/re-installing-wan-miniport-devices.aspx)

Comment: I have tried, it did not help. Thank you.

Comment: I tried way 2 ant it also did not help. I can not find reset.log file :(

Comment: @SonOfOmer `netsh int ipv4 reset C:\resetlog.txt` or `netsh int ip reset C:\resetlog.txt` ?

Comment: now it says: There's no user specified settings to be reset.

Comment: I tried way 4. I could not delete registry entry in second action. Neither I could set full permissions over registry.

Comment: @SonOfOmer See http://superuser.com/questions/547594/how-can-i-remove-all-com-ports-from-the-command-line-on-windows-7/547638#547638 change permission I add images to way too

Comment: I tried that it says "Unable to ave permission changes on #registry name# Access denied"

Comment: @SonOfOmer Run `regedit` with SYSTEM rights.Need Windows Driver Kit (WDK): `ntsd -c qd regedit`

Comment: @SonOfOmer http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11800 download.

Comment: You can run regedit with SYSTEM rights by using [PSExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) too, much smaller download. One of the examples they post is running regedit as SYSTEM. `psexec -i -d -s c:\windows\regedit.exe`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thx!

Answer (score 1):

From the Device Manager, navigate to Network Adapters and expand the tree.  Right click and uninstall the ethernet card and reboot.  Windows should autodetect the card and reinstall the appopriate drives.  This should re-enable IPv4.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Got to Networking and sharing then Click on change adapter.  Then right click on local area connection.

Double-click on Internet Protocol version 4 (TCP/IP4)
and change as follows:

[image]

save

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.