# How do I get Windows 10 to recognize my password to my Macintosh during network connection

Tags: networking, windows-10, ppc

It is critical that I connect to my Mac computers from my Windows system. They are on the same local ethernet.

I upgraded to Windows 10 which went very smoothly except for one hitch. I have two Mac computers, a modern one running El Capitan and an older Power PC running 10.6.4. (For legacy reasons I still need this system).

Windows 8 connected to both of these with no problem. Windows 10 connects to the new one as usual. For the PPC, it finds it on the network but rejects my password. I tried setting the password to none and still no luck.

I can connect to the PPC from the El Capitan Mac. I also tried no password. No luck.

Comment: Under the Username and password field on the W10 machine does it show a "Domain: HOSTNAME" message? If so try and login with \\username and password as normal.

Comment: No, That doesn't work.

Comment: I looked deeper into it and discovered that Windows 10 diagnostic says that it does not have permission to access the share name on the PowerPC. Somehow the share which has been accepted by all previous versions of Windows is now not OK. In the share settings on the Mac there is nothing about permissions.

Comment: I think, this may be what you're seeing: https://techjourney.net/cannot-connect-to-cifs-smb-samba-network-shares-shared-folders-in-windows-10/

Comment: That was a good lead. Thanks. But it doesn't work for me. The article seems to suggest that the problem being addressed is connecting to a Guest account which has no password. I trying to connect to an admin account with name and password. As I mentioned above this has always worked from Windows. And it still works on my newer Mac. But it no longer works on my older PowerPC. The new mac and old mac connect to each other without any problem.

Comment: Last idea would be to use a third party smb/cifs client, not windows explorer.

Comment: I did find a number of discussions about changing registry entries for NAS password encryption, for Guest access and also LMCompatibilityLevel. But none of that worked.

Comment: I found this discussion on older versions of smb [link](http://superuser.com/questions/947212/windows-10-upgrade-networking-totally-fried). I think it may have something to do with my problem. But it's way more technically complex than I want to deal with. I'm going to come up with a work-around to deal with this problem.