# How to uninstall/install the nic card, network properties protocol using powershell command or windows command line?

Tags: networking, command-line, powershell, c#

- I need to uninstall/install the protocol list in the nic card network properties list through command or code.

  - I tried the below command it's list the network properties list only.

    **Get-NetAdapterBinding -Name "MyAdapter" -AllBindings**

  But my scenario is uninstall/install the protocols

  - [Install Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/563056/install-internet-protocol-version-4-tcp-ipv4-on-windows-7)
  - This link, have the uninstall/install command but how to find my
    protocol name to pass the install/uninstall command?.
  - Protocol will be added in network property list following ways

**Install -> Protocol -> Add -> Select protocol -> Ok**

Uninstall, user can use the uninstall button

[image]

**Is it possible to uninstall or install nic card component through powershell script or command line ?**

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

Like you've noted, to just disable a binding on a specific interface (requires administrator privileges):

```
Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "Wi-Fi" -DisplayName "Client for Microsoft Networks"
```

The link you added refers to the `netsh interface $ProtocolName uninstall` command, but netsh only supports uninstalling the `ipv4` protocol (run `netsh interface` by itself to see the list of options).

These are each drivers that have been installed as a network binding. To uninstall these, you could use the [INetCfg APIs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/network/ff547694(v%3Dvs.85)), or use a tool like [NVSPBind](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Hyper-V-Network-VSP-Bind-cf937850), built specifically for this since environments like Server Core don't have the UI as an option. With NVSPBind, you can just run the following to unbind a protocol:

```
NVSPBind.exe /u $NIC $Protocol
```