# Removing Com ports in Windows 7 using cmd

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, windows-7, serial-port

I have been trying to find a way to make a script to uninstall specific COM-ports from Windows 7 that are no longer used.

**Background:**

I'm using NI Teststand to test a productio test of an USB-serial device. This test will change the FTDI config, so each device tested will use two COM-ports. It doens't take long time until there are hundreds of COM-ports present in the system.

**What I have tried:**

I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/547594/how-can-i-remove-all-com-ports-from-the-command-line-on-windows-7) suggestion, but it doesn't seem to work. I can see all the devices when i use:

```
devcon findall =ports
```

But from what I have gathered it is only possible to remove active devices using:

```
devcon remove
```

**Question:**

How can I remove a large number of COM-ports from CMD?

---

Thanks in advance

/Jaxc

Comment: Ah thanks, I thought it was there I was since thats where I clicked "sign up" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similiar issue to remove unused COM-Ports.
I am using "COM Name Arbiter Setter" from http://www.uwe-sieber.de/misc_tools_e.html

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: I checked the site and found [Device Cleanup Cmd](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/misc_tools_e.html). This tool looks like it doing exatcly what I needed: a way to remove inactive COM-ports from CMD.