# How to change number of COM port in a command line?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, serial-port, com

Is there away to change number of `COM` port in a command line?

I have many many devices and for each device Windows assigns different port number (and remembers this number!).

But in my case only one device is connected at any given time. I use serial port `COM` (using `USB`).

Therefore I want to use only one `COM` port, let's say `COM4`.

I know that there is a way to create some sort of a link, redirection, alias:

```
change port COM4=COM6
```

This works! Now I can use `COM4`.

But! Windows also increments `COM` port number by one (1). I want Windows to forget old devices and port numbers because I wish to connect more than 256 different devices. Therefore this just cannot happen:

```
change port COM4=COM270
```

Is there any chance that I can order Windows to forget old devices and port numbers? I know this can be done in *Device Manager* but I want to (and have to) do this in a command line.

I know there are also some other commands, for instance:

```
wmic path Win32_SerialPort
```

The commands above show ports information. Is possible to change port numbers using `wmic`?

Comment: Windows can only support up to 255 hardware COM ports.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://superuser.com/q/1110253/471143